# access to numbers in classification_report - sklearn

Tags: python, dictionary, scikit-learn, classification

This is a simple example of a `classification_report` in `sklearn`:

```
from sklearn.metrics import classification_report
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]
target_names = ['class 0', 'class 1', 'class 2']
print(classification_report(y_true, y_pred, target_names=target_names))
#             precision    recall  f1-score   support
#
#    class 0       0.50      1.00      0.67         1
#    class 1       0.00      0.00      0.00         1
#    class 2       1.00      0.67      0.80         3
#
#avg / total       0.70      0.60      0.61         5
```

I want to have access to avg/total row. For instance, I want to extract the `f1-score` from the report, which is 0.61.

How can I have access to the number in `classification_report`?

Comment: are you interested in the f1-score or extracting f1-score from classification report?

Comment: @PratikKumar extracting from classification report. I need other reports also.

Answer (score 25, accepted):

You can output the classification report by adding `output_dict=True` to the report:

```
report = classification_report(y_true, y_pred, output_dict=True)
```

And then access its single values as in a normal [python dictionary](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/python/python_dictionary.htm).

For example, the macro metrics:

```
macro_precision =  report['macro avg']['precision'] 
macro_recall = report['macro avg']['recall']    
macro_f1 = report['macro avg']['f1-score']
```

or Accuracy:

```
accuracy = report['accuracy']
```

Answer (score 21):

you can use `precision_recall_fscore_support` for getting all at once

```
from sklearn.metrics import precision_recall_fscore_support as score
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]
precision,recall,fscore,support=score(y_true,y_pred,average='macro')
print 'Precision : {}'.format(precision)
print 'Recall    : {}'.format(recall)
print 'F-score   : {}'.format(fscore)
print 'Support   : {}'.format(support)
```

here is the [link](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html) to the module

Comment: The answer is correct, but please note that you have used the wrong parameters, since the first parameter is `y_true`, the second one should be `y_pred`.

Comment: Does this also work for multi-class datasets?

Answer (score 9):

You can use output_dict parameter in build-in classification_report to return a dictionary:

`classification_report(y_true,y_pred,output_dict=True)`

Answer (score 5):

classification_report is string so I would suggest you to use f1_score from scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.metrics import f1_score
y_true = [0, 1, 2, 2, 2]
y_pred = [0, 0, 2, 2, 1]
target_names = ['class 0', 'class 1', 'class 2']

print(f1_score(y_true, y_pred, average=None)
```

output

Comment: Thank you. so there is no way to extract from classification_report? what about the other reports?

Comment: maybe you can use regex to extract this value. can you name the other reports ?

Comment: If you are talking about recall and precision, yes there are functions like recall_score and precision_score in sklearn

Answer (score 1):

You have to set the parameter `output_dict` to `True` it's not mentioned in the documentation but it is in repo [L2636](https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/7f9bad99d/sklearn/metrics/_classification.py#L2636)

##### Example

```py
report = classification_report(y_true, y_pred, 
                               output_dict=True) #<== Right here
```

This will output the dict with keys `report.keys()` the output is;

```
dict_keys(['0', '1', '2', 'accuracy', 'macro avg', 'weighted avg'])
```